# Trying to load the data as I scroll my listview

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to make the page load data as i scroll, so I made a scroll listener in my list builder then i made a fetch next function in my future builder.

But how can i call my fetchNext function which is in my future builder to call in my void scrollListener() {}.

Is it even right to paginate the data like this. Please help.

This is the list builder

```
class PostGridScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final String type, city, state;
  PostGridScreen({this.type, this.city, this.state});

  @override
  _PostGridScreenState createState() => _PostGridScreenState();
}

class _PostGridScreenState extends State<PostGridScreen>
    with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
  Future _getPosts;
  int documentLimit = 5;
  bool _hasNext = true;
  bool _isFetchingUsers = false;
  final _usersSnapshot = <DocumentSnapshot>[];
  final scrollController = ScrollController();

  var refreshKey = GlobalKey<RefreshIndicatorState>();
  @override
  void initState() {
    _fetchPosts();
    // scrollController.addListener(scrollListener);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    scrollController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

   void scrollListener() {}

  Future _fetchPosts() {
    return _getPosts = Provider.of<BaseProvider>(context, listen: false)
        .getPosts(widget.type, widget.city, widget.state, documentLimit);
  }

  Future<Null> refreshList() async {
    refreshKey.currentState?.show(atTop: false);
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2));

    setState(() {
      _fetchPosts();
    });

    return null;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);

    return RefreshIndicator(
      onRefresh: () => refreshList(),
      child: FutureBuilder(
          key: PageStorageKey('Page1'),
          future: _getPosts,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
              return ListView.builder(
                controller: scrollController,
                itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
//Fetch Next

                  Future fetchNextUsers() async {
                    if (_isFetchingUsers) return;
                    _isFetchingUsers = true;
                    try {
                      _getPosts =
                          Provider.of<BaseProvider>(context, listen: false)
                              .getPosts(
                                  widget.type,
                                  widget.city,
                                  widget.state,
                                  documentLimit,
                                  startAfter: _usersSnapshot.isNotEmpty
                                      ? _usersSnapshot.last
                                      : null);
                      _usersSnapshot.addAll(snapshot.data);
                      if (snapshot.data.length < documentLimit)
                        _hasNext = false;
                    } catch (e) {}
                    _isFetchingUsers = false;
                  }

//Tile

                  return GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => PostDetailScreen(
                          post: snapshot.data[index],
                        ),
                      ));
                    },
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                        top: 10,
                        bottom: 3.0,
                        right: 20.0,
                        left: 20.0,
                      ),
                      child: Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          boxShadow: [
                            BoxShadow(
                              color: Colors.black12,
                              offset: const Offset(
                                5.0,
                                5.0,
                              ),
                              blurRadius: 10.0,
                              spreadRadius: 2.0,
                            ), //BoxShadow
                          ],
                          color: Colors.blue,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                          image: DecorationImage(
                            image: NetworkImage(
                              snapshot.data[index]["imageUrl"],
                            ),
                            fit: BoxFit.cover,
                          ),
                        ),
                        height: 190.0,
                        width: 100,
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              );
            } else {
              return Center(
                child: Text("Loading..."),
              );
            }
          }),
    );
  }

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
}
```

This is the base provider

```
class BaseProvider with ChangeNotifier {

  final CollectionReference postsCollection =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("posts");


  //Fetching Data
  Future getPosts(String type, String city, String state, int limit,
      {DocumentSnapshot startAfter}) async {
    try {
      if (startAfter == null) {
        QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> response = await FirebaseFirestore
            .instance
            .collection("posts")
            .where('type', isEqualTo: type)
            .where('sellercity', isEqualTo: city)
            .where('sellerstate', isEqualTo: state)
            .limit(limit)
            .get();
        return response.docs;
      } else {
        QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> response = await FirebaseFirestore
            .instance
            .collection("posts")
            .where('type', isEqualTo: type)
            .where('sellercity', isEqualTo: city)
            .where('sellerstate', isEqualTo: state)
            .startAfterDocument(startAfter)
            .limit(limit)
            .get();
        return response.docs;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
      return e;
    }
  }
 
}
```

Comment: Answer is right here https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/pagination-in-flutter-using-firebase-cloud-firestore/

Answer (score 0):

if I understood correctly you want that your app doesn't load and render everything in a list at once and render them just in time it is shown to the user.
for achieving this you have to implement lazy loading which ListView.builder do this completely on its own so you don't need to worry about it

Comment: No No , i don't want like that. I want to load data from the firebase as i scroll my screen so i can use less reads.